# send data parameter to ckeditor dialog

Tags: dialog, ckeditor, contextmenu

I need to send parameters data to dialogbox
This is my code in plugin.js (right click)

```
editor.addCommand( 'editDialog', {
            exec: function( editor) {
                CKEDITOR.currentInstance.openDialog('editDialog');
            }
        });

    if ( editor.contextMenu )
            {

                editor.addMenuGroup( 'myGroup' );
                editor.addMenuItem( 'sliderItem',
                {
                    label : 'Edit Gallery',
                    command : 'editDialog',
                    group : 'myGroup'
                });
                editor.contextMenu.addListener( function( element )
                {

                    if ( element ){
                        element = element.getAscendant( 'wscms-gallery', true );
                    }

                    if ( element && !element.isReadOnly() && !element.data( 'cke-realelement' ) ){
                        return { sliderItem : CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_OFF};

                    }

                    return null;
                });
            }
```

I want when right click and click editgallery send any parameter to editDialog

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to declare the dialog in a separate file

**plugin.js:**

```
CKEDITOR.dialog.add('editDialog', this.path + 'dialogs/editDialog.js');//
```

Then, bind the command to the dialog instantiation:

```
editor.addCommand('editCommand', new CKEDITOR.dialogCommand('editDialog'));
```

Finally, in your dialog, handle the onShow event, to determine if you are editing an existing element or creating a new one:

**editDialog.js:**

```
onShow: function () {
  var node = 'wscms-gallery';
  var element = editor.getSelection().getStartElement();// Get the element at the start of the selection.
  if (element) {
    element = element.getAscendant(node, true);// Get the <node> element closest to the selection, if it exists.
  }

  if (!element || element.getName() !== node) {// Create a new <node> element if it does not exist.
    element = editor.document.createElement(node);
    this.insertMode = true;
  } else {
    this.insertMode = false;
  }

  this.element = element;
  console.log(element);
  if (!this.insertMode) {
    this.setupContent(this.element); //you MUST to implement the setup: method to get the parameters
  }
},
```

For further info, check [this example of simple plugin](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/plugin_sdk_sample_2.html)